# Angular: Lazy load a child module and inject its main component in the View of the Parent home component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading, router

I have a parent module where i'm **lazy loading** a child module

As you may see , i don't import my child module directly , but i'm loading it lazily under routing file :

**Parent Module :**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ParentRoutingModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    ParentRoutingModule
  ],

  declarations: [ParentComponent]
})
export class ParentModule { }
```

**Parent Routing Module :**

```
const parentRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: ParentHomeComponent}, 
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => ChildModule,
    canLoad: [ChildModuleGuard]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(parentRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class ParentRoutingModule { }
```

In my main ParentModule component ; the **ParentHomeComponent** i want to inject the view of my **ChildHomeCOmponent** , like this :

```
<p>
  Parent-home works!
</p>
<app-Child-home></app-Child-home>
```

> but this throws an error telling that the ChildHomeComponent isn't
>   part of the ParentModule (as i'm not importing it directly) ;

**How to deal with that ??**

I want that *if the module is loaded* , my **child home componen**t gets displayed under the **parent home component**

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: i don't think that it is possible as the lazy loaded module will be loaded when one of its routes is called and never before, if you need this component in the main module, you have to import it or add it to a shared module

Comment: did u solved this? I have a similiar problem

Answer (score 0):

This is not how lazy loading works in Angular.

Non-lazy loaded modules cannot access components from lazy loaded modules.